# Restriction of a measure to a sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $A,B$ two nonempty proper subsets of $X$ and $A \cup B \neq X$.

Define $\varepsilon := \lbrace A,B \rbrace \in \mathcal{P}(X)$.

$\mathcal{\sigma}(\varepsilon)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $\varepsilon$ and $\lambda : \varepsilon \to (0,\infty)$ a map.

How to prove that two different measures $\mu, \mu':\mathcal{\sigma(\varepsilon) \to [0,\infty]}$ exist with $\mu' \big|_{\varepsilon}=\mu \big|_{\varepsilon}=\lambda$ ?

I thought about showing that they give the same measure to each subinterval, but I don't know how to show the uniqueness on the restriction on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: This seems false.  Write $E=A\setminus B$, $F=B\setminus A$, and $G=A\cap B$.  Then $\sigma(\epsilon)=\sigma(\{E,F,G\})$. Now if $\mu$ and $\mu'$ agree on $E\cup G$ and $F\cup G$, then they agree on $E$, $F$, and $G$ (by disjointness).  Hence they agree on $\sigma(\epsilon)$. Right?

Comment: Assume that there exists a measure $\mu$ on $\sigma(\epsilon)$ such that $\mu|_{\epsilon} = \lambda$. (This need not always be true. Consider the case $A=B$ and $\lambda(A)\neq\lambda(B)$.) Now let $a\in[0,\infty]$ and $\mu_a$ be obtained from $\mu$ by replacing the value of $\mu(X\setminus(A\cup B))$ by $a$. (This is possible because $X\setminus(A\cup B)$ is non-empty.) Then $\mu_a|_{\epsilon} = \mu|_{\epsilon}$ but we can make $\mu_a\neq\mu$ by choosing an appropriate value of $a$.